# REACT spa app - serving separate and different prerendered static html for SEO, benefits and drawbacks

Tags: html, reactjs, seo, single-page-application, prerender

Are there any benefits or drawbacks if you serving light version of page optimized for SEO if bots crawls and if people come from web then react SPA which completely javascript application.

Basically question is, is there practice to actually serve like short HTML version which contains only SEO important things and rips off everything else for bots and full page for users.

Is there any use case or example that somebody have used this technique?

Comment: How would you ensure that the lite version is kept up to date?  Would it automatically reflect changes as your site changed?

Answer (score 1):

This would be seen as [Cloaking](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/66355?hl=en) by the crawlers and could get your site penalized in the search results. If you are serving a prerendered page, you will want to make sure it is the exact page that your users will see after the javascript has been executed in order to prevent any cloaking issues.

Answer (score 0):

You'll could mount [prerender](https://prerender.io/):

> The Prerender.io middleware that you install on your server will check each request to see if it's a request from a crawler. If it is a request from a crawler, the middleware will send a request to Prerender.io for the static HTML of that page. If not, the request will continue on to your normal server routes. The crawler never knows that you are using Prerender.io since the response always goes through your server.

Comment: You didnt understood question. Point is about benefits or drawbacks to serve different lite content-oriented prerendered version to bots and actual application to users.

Answer (score 0):

The Prerender.io middleware that you install on your server will check each request to see if it's a request from a crawler. If it is a request from a crawler, the middleware will send a request to Prerender.io for the static HTML of that page. If not, the request will continue on to your normal server routes. The crawler never knows that you are using Prerender.io since the response always goes through your server.

[Quora SEO post](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-best-techniques-for-off-page-SEO/answer/CMT-Direct-2?prompt_topic_bio=1)
[taekwondomonfils.com SEO](https://www.taekwondomonfils.com/board/board_topic/5750834/5738649.htm?page=1)